# Laptop show blank screen after power on

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, blank-screen

My MSI GX740(warranty expired) shows only blank screen after power up, not even the POST screen.

This happened after it hang at Windows 7 loading screen(before logon screen), I pressed the power button to turn it off and lead to all these.

Here is what I did so far:

- Connect to external TV via HDMI, TV said "No signal". HDMI cable not faulty because I tested with another laptop.
- Switch out RAMs with other RAMs, still blank screen.
- Take out the HDD and connect to other laptop, it's working as external HDD.
- Unplug all power source, press power button for 30 seconds then try again, still blank screen.

Here is what I observed so far:

- Fan is running.
- No other light indicator except the power light, HDD light not blinking.
- CD\DVD ROM can be eject.
- Those multimedia buttons above the keyboard are functioning, the light came on when I press it.

According to Google, depleted BIOS battery should not cause this.

I don't feel comfortable to switch out the processor or GPU. I don't know how anyway.

What could be the cause?

What else can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: 1. get a hold of USB BIOS error code reader (very very cheap)

Comment: 2. AS youve said, open the laptop disconnect HDD, ODD ( lessen the power consumption ) try to power on.
3. get a Voltmeter and check if PSU is giving right amounts out.
4. Check on mobo from AC soldering point if electricity is coming in the MOBO
5. When laptop dissasembled, remove the HEATSINK and check when powering on if GPU chip is overheating realy fast.

Answer (score 0):

Did face a very same case for a few weeks ago, sorry, nothing helped on that ...

Probably, the BIOS ROM is corrupted/dead, and can't be loaded into the CPU for POST/Boot procedure. It's very hard to get the BIOS re-loaded to the ROM "at home". The easy way would be a new m/b ...

There is available e.g. at Phoenix a BIOS rescue procedure based on an USB stick re-load, but didn't get it working, because the USB wasn't either recognized at Boot. And, e.g. on HP machines there has some time been a BIOS re-load procedure by some key-combination, but do not know the present status of such.

Please, some interesting background info on this at these maybe slightly outdated chart/pages -> http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up/ .

Answer (score 0):

My old laptop experienced the same issue. In my case it was a GPU failure.

The guy at the S-Center said my main board dead and need to be replaced. But I bring my lap to another shop and let them fix my GPU, I don't really know what they did but it was quick and only cost a few dollars. After that my Laptop can boot up again.

ps1. Before my Lap can't boot up, the graphic driver crashed occasionally, sometimes it can recover immediately, sometimes it freeze the PC and I had to do a hard reset just like you. If you have the same symptom, I think you should let someone look at your GPU.

ps2. My GPU was a AMD Radeon.